# Tuning Apache & CentOS 7 for Backups

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, rds, mysql-backup, remote-backup

**My Setup**
Uncompressed my webserver files take up about 4GB of space and the used MySQL database is about 4GB as well. MySQL is running on a remote Amazon RDS instance and the webserver is on an EC2 in the same region.

The steps of my backup are this...

1. Compress public_html => public_html.gz
2. Dump Remote DB
3. Compress DB to db.gz
4. Compress public_html.gz, db.gz => backup.gz
5. Uploaded backup.gz to Amazon S3 bucket

The server runs on 3.5 GB RAM with two cores.

**My problem**
During the backup my website becomes unbearably slow. However, CPU usage peaks at 5% and RAM peaks at 1 GB when at least 2 GB is free to consume. This leads me to believe that the database could be at fault for the slow performance but I have very little experience with MySQL configuration and, if it is to blame, am not sure what needs to be done to speed up the backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Amazon RDS why are you running a manual backups?

Please go read the RDS documentation and enable Automated Backups.

**Working With Automated Backups:**

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithAutomatedBackups.html

Once you have removed that from you backup 'script' check you performance.

I suggest you try one of the following for backing up your website:

1. If you website doesn't have any user generated content then use
   GIT.
2. If you website does have user generated content then look at
   AWS snapshots.